# OOP PDO Global Variables within Class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am looking into oop to enhance my web dev knowledge. At the moment i am having a bit of an issue. I have created a Database class that contains all the queries etc. ( fetch, count, etc. ) This just allows the queries or updates to take up less space in the other classes etc. The issue i am having is passing this class along and making it globally accessible. I have used

```
global $db;
```

within a class function but i read that it is bad practice to use that. I also do not want to pass the $db variable as a parameter if i did i would have to change a lot of my current classes and it would just be easier if i can make $db globally available in a "good" practice way.

I can provide my Database class if necessary it is just a simple class with the variable that initiates the connection through construct.

( Second Question )

I was also reading about the singleton instance function, before implementing i read that it was also considered bad practice. Is there something that should take its place?

( I decided to place the class below )

```
class Database {
    private $host      = 'localhost';
    private $user      = 'xxx';
    private $pass      = 'xxxx';
    private $dbname    = 'xxxxx';

    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING, 
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
        );
        // Create PDO Instance
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }

    public function fetch($sql, $param = "") {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

        if (empty($param)) {
            $this->stmt->execute();
        } else {
            $this->stmt->execute($param);
        }

        return $this->stmt->fetch();
    }
}

$db = new Database();
```

An example of what i am attempting to accomplish is as follows
( User Profile Page )

```
class User {
    function set_user($input) {
        if (is_numeric($input)) {
            $this->user = $input;
        } else {
            $user = $db->fetch("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE url=:url", array(':url' => $input));
            $this->user = $user['userid'];
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What does your `Database` class offer over using regular `PDO`? These PHP database wrapper classes are so redundant

Comment: *"I also do not want to pass the $db variable as a parameter if i did i would have to change a lot of my current classes and it would just be easier if i can make $db globally available in a "good" practice way"* ~ passing the instance as a parameter (dependency injection) **is** the *good practice* way. Alternatively, I suppose you could use a dependency injection container. Search github, there's loads of them

Comment: The only benefit from using these wrappers include saving line space. For example if i did not use the wrapper each query, etc. would take up 4 line spaces when using this wrapper i condense that same code into 1 line. My current project is a cms so there are A LOT of queries and it has saved so much space and time.

Comment: You can automate the class loading, e.g. `$app->User` will return `new User(new Database)` or at least `new User(Database::getInstance())`

Comment: Check out http://php-di.org/, looks awesome.

Comment: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: @Phil it could be interesting though to be able to method chain your PDO calls: `$db->prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE it=? AND was=?')->execute(array($value1,$value2))->fetch()` which is sadly not the case with regular PDO. defining custom `fetch()` method kinda emulates this

Answer (score -1):

AN issue with your approach is not the global var, but that the DB connection is permanently open. It is not always good. This is kind of service object and it is not partiularily bad to have it globally visible.

If you don't want it global and want to solve the open connection issue, you can easily close the connection in the destructor, remove the global var and create/use/delete the DB wherever required.

Another approach would be not to use singleton, but so called **service class**. Make DB class not instanciable, but rather define service methods (all static) - open, close, execute, or whatever. Than the DB clients should not create DB object, but only access the static methods. This approach fits the reality very nice, as DB-access is seen as a service.

Comment: I have read that singleton approach is not "recommended". I ended up just including the db as a parameter to save time. When it comes to the database what is the reason for closing the connection per page? If all pages are database content driven ( CMS ) what would be the reason to close the db connection at end of page load?

Comment: Concurrency for example. What happens is two pages try to use the same DB object and there is only one connection?